# wxPython - ListCrtl and SQLite3

Tags: wxpython

I'm trying to get a SQLite3 DB to populate a wx.ListCrtl. I can get it to print to stdout/stderr without any problem. I just can't seem to figure out how to display the data in the DataWindow/DataList? I'm sure I've made some code mistakes, so any help is appreciated.

Main.py

```
import wx
import wx.lib.mixins.listctrl  as  listmix
from database import *
import sys

class DataWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, 'DataList', size=(640,480))
        self.win = DataList(self)
        self.Center()
        self.Show(True)

class DataList(wx.ListCtrl, listmix.ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin, listmix.ColumnSorterMixin):
    def __init__(self, parent = DataWindow):
        wx.ListCtrl.__init__( self, parent, -1, style=wx.LC_REPORT|wx.LC_VIRTUAL|wx.LC_HRULES|wx.LC_VRULES)

        #building the columns
        self.InsertColumn(0, "Location")
        self.InsertColumn(1, "Address")
        self.InsertColumn(2, "Subnet")
        self.InsertColumn(3, "Gateway")
        self.SetColumnWidth(0, 100)
        self.SetColumnWidth(1, 150)
        self.SetColumnWidth(2, 150)
        self.SetColumnWidth(3, 150)

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent = None, id = -1, title = "MainWindow"):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size = (800,600),
                          style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE ^ (wx.RESIZE_BORDER))

        # StatusBar
        self.CreateStatusBar()

        # Filemenu
        filemenu = wx.Menu()

        # Filemenu - About
        menuitem = filemenu.Append(-1, "&About", "Information about this application")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onAbout, menuitem)

        #Filemenu - Data
        menuitem = filemenu.Append(-1, "&Data", "Get data")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onData, menuitem)
        # Filemenu - Seperator
        filemenu.AppendSeparator()

        #Filemenu - Exit
        menuitem = filemenu.Append(-1, "&Exit", "Exit the application")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onExit, menuitem)

        # Menubar
        menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        menubar.Append(filemenu, "&File")
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

        # Show
        self.Show(True)
        self.Center()

    def onAbout(self, event):
        pass

    def onData(self, event):
        DataWindow(self)
        callDb = Database()
        sql = "SELECT rowid, address, subnet, gateway FROM pod1"
        records = callDb.select(sql)
        for v in records:
            print "How do I get the records on the DataList?"
            #print "%s%s%s" % (v[1],v[2],v[3])
            #for v in records:
            #DataList.InsertStringItem("%s") % (v[0], v[1], v[2])

    def onExit(self, event):
        self.Close()
        self.Destroy()

    def onSave(self, event):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainWindow(None, -1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

database.py

```
import os
import sqlite3

class Database(object):

    def __init__(self, db_file="data/data.sqlite"):
        database_allready_exists = os.path.exists(db_file)
        self.db = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        if not database_allready_exists:
            self.setupDefaultData()

    def select(self,sql):
        cursor = self.db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql)
        records = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.close
        return records

    def insert(self,sql):
        newID = 0
        cursor = self.db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql)
        newID = cursor.lastrowid
        self.db.commit()
        cursor.close()
        return newID

    def save(self,sql):
        cursor = self.db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql)
        self.db.commit()
        cursor.close()

    def setupDefaultData(self):
        pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do it like this. I'm not even sure why, I just copied the code (roughly) from the demo, and the documentation isn't very clear:

```
    count = 0
    for v in records:
        index = DataList.InsertStringItem(sys.maxint, str(count + 1))

        DataList.SetStringItem(index, 0, v['rowid'])
        DataList.SetStringItem(index, 1, v['address'])
        count += 1
```

the number is a reference to the column to set the string for. Really unsure of index, to be honest

Comment: Thank for the tip, I'm still trying to get it to work. It's throwing up the error.
TypeError: unbound method InsertStringItem() must be called with DataList instance as first argument (got int instance instead)

Comment: You need an instance of your data list. e.g. in onData() you say DataWindow(self) - but you need to assign this to a variable. 
data = DataWindow(self)
now perform your actions on the .win attribute of the data variable -- data.win.InsertString...